# Is there any way to collect dataframe value as list without using collect()

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing a challenge in efficiently filtering a Spark DataFrame without resorting to using the collect method, which can lead to performance issues on large datasets. Specifically, I need to filter rows from a DataFrame where a column value is not present in a list obtained from another DataFrame.

I have two DataFrames, df1 and df2, and I want to filter df1 based on values in one of its columns, let's say "gold", which should not be present in columns "silver" or "bronze" from df2.

The approach I've tried involves using collect, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// df1 and df2 are assumed to be already defined

val filteredDF = df1.filter(not(col("gold").isin(df2.select("silver").union(df2.select("bronze")).collect.map(_.getString(0)): _*)))
```

I was able to solve the above via spark SQL:

```
val result = sc.sql(
      """
        |select gold as player_name, count(1) as no_of_player
        |from olympic_table
        |where gold not in (select silver from olympic_table union all select bronze from olympic_table)
        |group by 1
        |""".stripMargin)
    result.show()
```

However, I'm looking for an alternative to achieve this filtering operation without resorting to collect. Is there a way to obtain the values from the DataFrame as a list or any other structure directly within the DataFrame API to avoid bringing the data to the driver node?

Any suggestions, insights, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use a left outer join with an isnull test on the resulting (silver or bronze) field.

Comment: @talkdatatome are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula no I am not

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 : Use `ANTI JOIN` - Simple

```
WITH
    olympic AS (
        (
            SELECT silver AS gold
            FROM olympic_table
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT bronze AS gold
            FROM olympic_table
        )
    ),
    gold_cte AS (
        SELECT 
          l.gold AS player_name, 
          COUNT(1) AS no_of_player
        FROM gold l 
        ANTI JOIN olympic r 
        ON l.gold = r.gold
        GROUP BY l.gold
    )
SELECT 
  player_name,
  no_of_player
FROM gold_cte
```

Approach 2 : Use `HOF - Higher Order Functions` - Complex

```
WITH
    gold_cte AS (
        SELECT ARRAY_EXCEPT (
                COLLECT_LIST (gold), 
                FLATTEN (
                    COLLECT_SET (
                        ARRAY(
                            silver, 
                            bronze
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) as input
        FROM olympic_table
    )
SELECT INLINE (
        ARRAY_DISTINCT (
            TRANSFORM (
                input, e -> NAMED_STRUCT (
                    'player_name', e, 'no_of_player', SIZE (FILTER (input, f -> f = = e))
                )
            )
        )
    )
FROM gold_cte
```